# Estimating individual components of a mixture distribution

Tags: mixture-distribution

I am trying to jointly estimate the components of a mixture distribution.

I have a sampling from a mixture, `XY`, composed of `X` and `Y` with a known mixing parameter `m`. I also have a separate sampling of just `Y`. I am trying to estimate the the PDF of `X`.

Here is a concrete example.

```
# Generate XY sampling data
m <- 0.2 # Mixing parameter
n <- 1000
k <- rbinom(1, n, prob = m)
xy <- c(rnorm(n-k, 1, 1), rnorm(k, 5, 0.5))

# Estimate XY_pdf
XY_pdf <- density(xy)
plot(XY_pdf)

# Generate independent Y sampling data
y2 <- rnorm(500, mean = 5, sd = 0.5)
Y_pdf <- density(y2, bw = XY_pdf$bw)
lines(Y_pdf$x, Y_pdf$y*m, col = "red", lty=2)

# Function for calculating P_kde; https://stackoverflow.com/a/34682302/2723734
kde_val <- function(x, t, bw){
  sapply(t, function(ti) {
    kernelValues <- rep(0,length(x))
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
      transformed = (ti - x[i]) / bw
      kernelValues[i] <- dnorm(transformed, mean = 0, sd = 1) / bw
    }
    return(sum(kernelValues) / length(x))
  })
}

t <- seq(-3, 9, by = 0.01)
xy_val <- kde_val(xy, t, XY_pdf$bw)
y_val  <- kde_val(y2, t, Y_pdf$bw) * m
x_val_est <- xy_val - y_val
lines(t, x_val_est, col = "blue")
```

[image]

The plot shows `PDF(XY)` and `PDF(Y)` estimated from KDE (black and red); and an estimate of `PDF(X) = PDF(XY) - PDF(Y)*m` (blue).

The estimate of `PDF(X)` is pretty good, except towards the tail where it becomes negative due to sampling variation in XY and Y.

**How do I properly estimate `PDF(X)`?**

(I can't assume the distributions are gaussian)

Comment: Because your code does not implement a sample from a mixture distribution (it instead aggregates samples of known sizes, [which is not the same thing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/64058/919)), some clarification would be helpful. By "mixing parameter" $m$ do you mean you know exactly a proportion $m$ of the data come from $X$?  If so, could you explain how value of $m$ is known?

Comment: @whuber Yes I see your point about aggregating vs. mixing. In the real problem, the sample sizes are a lot larger so it is approximately the same. I'll edit the question to use a sampling. Without getting into too much detail, I have a very good estimate of `m` from a previous experiments in identical conditions.

Comment: It's helpful to know $n$ is large in your application.  I wonder at which size it starts making a difference, though.

Comment: I am not sure. Does the edit look like the correct sampling approach to generate data?

Comment: For a generally correct approach, see the code in the link I provided in the first comment. A quick glance at your code suggests it ought to work correctly, but there's a simpler way: `n <- 1000;
k <- rbinom(1, n, prob = m);
xy <- c(rnorm(k, 1, 1), rnorm(n-k, 5, 0.5))` Even that's not quite correct, because the values don't occur randomly.  When it matters, this works: `i <- sample.int(2, 1000, prob=c(m, 1-m), replace=TRUE);
xy <- rnorm(length(i), ifelse(i==1, 1, 5), ifelse(i==1, 1, 0.5))` You can also just execute a final `sample(xy)` to randomize the data.

Comment: Do you have any priors on the distribution of $X$? Or criteria for what would be most reasonable? If not, I would take $f_0=f_{XY}-mf_Y$ and modify it to look nice, keep an integral of $1-m$ and stay non-negative — in this case $f_X=\max(0,f_0)$ on $x<5$ and $f_X=0$ for $x>5$ might work.

Comment: @MattF one assumption/prior I can make is that the right side of the mixture distribution should be dominated by Y (and vice versa on the left side for X). So I was thinking that the ratio of PDF(X)/PDF(Y) is monotonic and asymptotic. I don't like the idea of flooring the value at zero, since it makes the resulting PDF non-differentiable. I'm looking for a more principled approach.

Comment: A more differentiable approach is to find $\mu$ and $\sigma$ which best fit $f_Y/f_{XY} =F_{N(\mu,\sigma)}$; there might even be plausible probabilitistc processes which would lead to that equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, you estimated the overall mixture distribution using a KDE, and estimated the second mixture component using a KDE fit to another dataset sampled exclusively from that component. You then tried to obtain the first mixture component by subtracting the latter KDE from the  former, scaled by the mixing weight. Unfortunately, this doesn't yield a valid probability density function, as seen by the negative density values in the plot. Furthermore, both datasets contain information about the second mixture component. Estimating this component using only one dataset fails to take advantage of this information, yielding a suboptimal estimate for both mixture components.

A more principled method should simultaneously estimate both mixture components using all available data. Below, I'll describe how to do this using a maximum likelihood approach.

#### Approach

Changing the notation for clarity, suppose the mixture distribution is:

$$p(x \mid \theta_1, \theta_2) = m p_1(x \mid \theta_1) + (1-m) p_2(x \mid \theta_2)$$

where and $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the mixture components (parameterized by $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$) and $m \in [0,1]$ is a known parameter controlling the mixing strength. Let $X^A$ be a dataset sampled i.i.d. from the mixture distribution and $X^B$ be a dataset sampled i.i.d. from the second mixture component alone. The log likelihood for both datasets is:

$$L(\theta_1, \theta_2) =
\sum_{x \in X^A} \log p(x \mid \theta_1, \theta_2)
+ \sum_{x \in X^B} \log p_2(x \mid \theta_2)$$

The parameters for both components are simultaneously estimated by maximizing the likelihood for both datasets:

$$\max_{\theta_1, \theta_2} \ L(\theta_1, \theta_2)$$

If a simple parametric form is known for the  mixture components, this should be used. Otherwise, the components must be modeled using a flexible family of density functions that can reasonably approximate many possible shapes. For example, each component could itself be represented as a mixture distribution (as in the example below). One could also use spline-based density functions, or various other possibilities.

#### Example

I generated toy data using $m=0.7$ and Weibull mixture components with different shapes (since the question specifies that they''re non-Gaussian). To mimic the situation where the true parametric family is unknown, I modeled each mixture component as a weighted KDE:

$$p_1(x \mid \theta_1) =
\sum_{i=1}^k w^1_i \mathcal{N}(x \mid \mu_i, \sigma^2)$$

$$p_2(x \mid \theta_2) =
\sum_{i=1}^k w^2_i \mathcal{N}(x \mid \mu_i, \sigma^2)$$

This approximates each mixture component as a weighted sum of $k$ Gaussian kernels centered over the common 'prototype points' in $\mu$ (which I set equal to $X^A$). Kernels have a fixed bandwidth $\sigma$ (which I set to $0.4$). Unlike a regular KDE, each kernel has a different weight; the two mixture components are distinguished by their different weight vectors $w^1$ and $w^2$. I parameterized the weight vectors using the softmax function. This constrains them to be non-negative and sum to one, ensuring that they're always valid:

$$w^1 = \operatorname{softmax}(\theta_1) \quad
w^2 = \operatorname{softmax}(\theta_2)$$

Note that $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are vectors with an entry for each point in $X^A$. I fit them by numerically maximizing the log likelihood $L(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ as described above, using the BFGS algorithm.

The following plot shows the true and estimated mixture distributions, along with the individual mixture components (scaled by $m$ and $1-m$, respectively).

[image]

Note that the estimated mixture components are 'leaning in' slightly at the edges. This reflects the difficulty of approximating a skewed, non-Gaussian distribution as a sum of Gaussian kernels with identical bandwidths. This could be resolved by decreasing the kernel bandwidth, allowing the bandwidth to vary across kernels, or by using a different family of approximating distributions. The first two choices would produce a more flexible model, requiring more data.

Comment: Thank you, this looks solid! I'm eager to code this up and try it out on my data.

Comment: @thc glad to help

Comment: I just wanted to follow-up that this worked extremely well on my real data. I ended up parameterizing the thetas as 5-parameter logistic curves, as allowing each theta value to vary independently was too much computationally.

Comment: @thc Great! Thanks for the update, I'm glad to hear it's working and that you found a good parameterization

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem.  My basic approach is to fit a kernel density estimate as the question suggested, but adjust the bandwidth to see if I can find a bandwidth for $XY$ and a bandwidth for $Y$ such that $X$ is never negative.  I don't think a solution is guaranteed, but it worked in my examples.  To find the bandwidths, I used a machine learning approach with a cost function constructed to ensure there are no negative sections of the $X$ pdf and to ensure that the bandwidths don't get inflated.  I don't have a reference for this, but I couldn't find anything directly on point here.

Also, note that I think the pdf equation should be: $f_{XY} = (1-m)f_X + mf_Y$ so $f_X = \frac{1}{1-m} (f_{XY} - mf_Y)$

```r
# x = points to evalue density
# xi = data from a random sample of the distribution
# bw = bandwidth
my_density <- function(x, xi, bw)
{
  # kernel is a standard normal pdf
  n <- length(xi)
  return(sapply(x, function(z) {
    1 / n / bw * sum(dnorm((z - xi) / bw))
  }))
};

# par = optimization parameters, bandwidth for A1 and for A
# A1 = component distribution
# A = mixture distribution (A = (1-m)*A2 + m*A1)
# m = mixture proportion
# grid = points to evalute the densities on
densitycost <- function(par, A1, A, m, grid, lambda)
{
  densityA1 <- my_density(grid, A1, par[1])
  densityA <- my_density(grid, A, par[2])
  densityA2 <- (densityA - m * densityA1) / (1 - m)
  # the cost is height of the areas where the A1 density is more than A and a parameter to control parameter inflation away from 1 (the standard deviation of the kernel)
  sum(ifelse(densityA2 >= 0, 0, densityA2^2)) + lambda*((par[1] - 1)^2 + (par[2] - 1)^2)
};

# Generate XY sampling data
set.seed(1843948)
m <- 0.2 # Mixing parameter
nxy <- 1000
ny <- 500
k <- rbinom(1, nxy, prob = m)
xy <- c(rnorm(nxy - k, 1, 1), rnorm(k, 5, 0.5))
# Generate independent Y sampling data
y <- rnorm(ny, mean = 5, sd = 0.5)
# histogram grid
z <- seq(-5, 11, length=100)

# With a lambda = 0, the optimizer finds a best solution, but it is a large bandwidth
o <- optim(par = c(1, 1), fn = densitycost, A1 = y, A = xy, m = m, grid = z, lambda = 0)

density_xy <- my_density(z, xy, o$par[2])
density_y <- my_density(z, y, o$par[1])
density_x <- (my_density(z, xy, o$par[2]) - m * my_density(z, y, o$par[1])) / (1 - m)

any(density_x < 0)
#> [1] FALSE

plot(z, density_xy, type = "l", col = "blue", xlab = "", ylab = "Density", ylim = c(0, 0.4))
lines(z, density_y, col = "red")
lines(z, density_x, col = "green")
```

[image]

```r
# With a lambda = 0.1, you get a density that follows the mixture better, but allows for a negative X density
o <- optim(par = c(1, 1), fn = densitycost, A1 = y, A = xy, m = m, grid = z, lambda = 0.1)

density_xy <- my_density(z, xy, o$par[2])
density_y <- my_density(z, y, o$par[1])
density_x <- (my_density(z, xy, o$par[2]) - m * my_density(z, y, o$par[1])) / (1 - m)

any(density_x < 0)
#> [1] TRUE

plot(z, density_xy, type = "l", col = "blue", xlab = "", ylab = "Density", ylim = c(0, 0.4))
lines(z, density_y, col = "red")
lines(z, density_x, col = "green")
```

[image]